# How to find records from a field that contains an int array?

Tags: sql-server

Table `T1` contains 3 records:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 101,103,115,189 | NAME1 |
| 101,115 | NAME2 |
| 102,116 | NAME3 |

I have to find all rows from column `A` that contain (101,102,115) which are NAME1, NAME2 and NAME3. Since there are over 100000 rows, I need to find an effective way. I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: The most correct answer is "don't store your data like that in the first place" because comma-separated values like this are against many of the core principles of database design. Since you're on SQL Server 2014, you'll need a user-defined TVF that can split the values, then you'll `CROSS APPLY` that with the remainder of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bbb78c/6)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Testdata
(
    SomeID INT,
    A VARCHAR(MAX),
    B VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT Testdata SELECT 1,  '101,103,115,189', 'NAME1'
INSERT Testdata SELECT 2, '101,115' ,'NAME2'
INSERT Testdata SELECT 3, '102,116' , 'NAME3'
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH tmp(SomeID, B, DataItem, A) AS
(
    SELECT
        SomeID,
        B,
        LEFT(A, CHARINDEX(',', A + ',') - 1),
        STUFF(A, 1, CHARINDEX(',', A + ','), '')
    FROM Testdata
    UNION all

    SELECT
        SomeID,
        B,
        LEFT(A, CHARINDEX(',', A + ',') - 1),
        STUFF(A, 1, CHARINDEX(',', A + ','), '')
    FROM tmp
    WHERE
        A > ''
)



select distinct B from tmp where DataItem IN ('101','102','115')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bbb78c/6/0)**:

```
|     B |
|-------|
| NAME1 |
| NAME2 |
| NAME3 |
```